# Replacing GitHub UI sequence with git or hub commands

Tags: git, github, scripting

We currently prepare a release for QA by merging from Dev as follows using GitHub and manually doing the following:

- go to the repository
- request a pull on the repo (click Pull Request)
- set up merge of Dev into QA (select QA on the left, Dev on the right)
- add a comment "Merging Dev into QA" and click Create Pull Request
- I'm the only one working on it, so never any conflicts
- create the pull request (click Merge Pull Request)
- confirm the pull request (click Confirm Merge)

Is there a way to do this in `git` or `hub`, including the record of the pull request, so it can be scripted?

Comment: Can should api the github

Comment: Do you want me to try creating a script from git bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with `hub` like you suggested, you can simply:

- Make a file `pull_request_template.md` with content `Merging Dev into QA`. If you'd like, you can add more lines to the file, and the first line will act as the title, the rest will be the body.
- `hub pull-request -F pull_request_template.md -b Dev -h QA | hub merge` to both open a PR and merge it

Note, since `hub` is meant to be a drop-in replacement for `git`, you should run the command from the context of your repo's local directory.

For more info on these commands, see their docs: [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html), [`pull-request`](https://hub.github.com/hub-pull-request.1.html), and [`hub-merge`](https://hub.github.com/hub-merge.1.html).

Comment: Are the repository and branches required somewhere?

Comment: Yes, good catch - the branches are, I’ll correct the answer. The repository is implicit based on the remotes in your local repo, I believe

Answer (score 2):

**This sequence of commands is not advised to be automated in general**

Simply because a lot can go wrong when you expect it the least (or a lot of conditions need to be taken into account). If you are the only one working on the project, it seems to be acceptable, but keep in mind that the merge may actually fail. Even if you are working on the project yourself.

Also, the principle of Pull Requests has its major benefit - **code review**.
Ideally, you should never accept such request without checking if everything is really as it should be. Therefore, I don't see myself any reason why you would like to do that; creating a regular merge commit (and possibly adding a tag) in regular Git seems more reasonable.

**But if you really want that...**

Send POST request to `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls` with JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Merging Dev into QA",
  "head": "dev",
  "base": "qa"
}
```

to create the pull request. Response contains in `['number']` the identifier of the pull request or grab the 'Location' header which contains the URI of the just created pull request.

To merge the pull request make a PUT request to: `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge`

For more detailed info on API (and authentication to the API), see: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. Also, will be checking the results to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "including the record of the pull request"(because it's a ul version of the merge)  but I have my own script to release hope helps you:

```
git checkout dev
```

to switch dev branch

```
git fetch https://gitlab.com/xx/xx.git
```

fetch changes on upstream of the master branch

```
git commit -a -m "changes"
```

commit your local changes:

```
git pull https://gitlab.com/xx/xx.git
```

get pull request from upstream

```
git checkout master
```

now switch to master branch

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff dev
```

if you want to do a review before merge use above comment if not remove parameters

```
git push origin master
```

push your changes to the master branch

```
git reset --merge
```

If you wish to back those changes, just reset that merge.

Edit: You can wite blow command as a bash or shell script